# Не срабатывает условие if для двух символов

Tags: c, алгоритм

Написал функцию с переменным количеством аргументов, которая разделяет исходную(введенную пользователем) строку по разделителям, указанным в аргументах этой функции, и возвращает массив разделенных строк:

```
char** SplitString(char *rawString, int argAmount, ...)
{
    int i, j, newStringIndexCounter;
    va_list argPtr;
    int flag = 0;
    char *cur = rawString;
    newStringIndexCounter = 0;
    j = 0;

    char **newStrings = (char**)calloc(81, sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < 81; i++)
    {
        newStrings[i] = (char*)calloc(80, sizeof(char));
    }

    while (*cur != '\0')
    {
        flag = 0;
        va_start(argPtr, rawString);

        for (i = 0; i < argAmount; i++)
        {
            if (*cur == va_arg(argPtr, char))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag != 1)
        {
            newStrings[newStringIndexCounter][j] = *cur;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            newStrings[newStringIndexCounter][j] = '\0';
            j = 0;
            newStringIndexCounter++;
        }
        cur++;
        va_end(argPtr);
    }
    newStringIndexCounter++;
    strcpy(newStrings[newStringIndexCounter], "EoS");
    return newStrings;
}
```

Вот пример использования этой функции(подразумевается, что память под массив строк `char **newStrings` выделена):

```
newStrings = SplitString(rawString, 3, '/', ';', '^');
```

Программа работает стабильно, но есть одна проблема - исходная строка никогда не разделяется по последнему аргументу. То есть, как в примере - последний аргумент '^'. Если в rawString будет что-то типа test1^test2, то строка не разделится на две.

Попытался продебажить - выяснилось, что во время цикла

```
 for (i = 0; i < argAmount; i++)
        {
            if (*cur == va_arg(argPtr, char))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
```

при сравнении `*cur == va_arg(argPtr, char)` не срабатывает равенство. В дебаггере пишет, что вместо символа `'^'` `va_arg` возвращает какой-то `'\x3'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Черт. Надо больше спать. Когда модифицировал функцию, забыл сменить в вызове `va_start(argPtr, rawString)` на `va_start(argPtr, argAmount)`

Тема закрыта.